# Does `du` list every single file on a system?

Tags: debian, command-line, files

Does `du /` list ***every single file?***  Is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, du will list all the files ?
What do you mean a better way ? betterway to do what ? list all the files ?

Comment: Please do not post the same question on multiple StackExchange sites http://superuser.com/q/1114010/493903

Answer (score 2):

If the objective is listing every file/folder on the file system, then you could use `ls` with the recursive option `-R`

```
# ls -R /
```

If you're trying to filter the files say using size, then do

```
# find / -type f -size +10c
```

The above commands gives you the files( the `-type f` option) which are greater than 10 bytes(the `c` option) in  size.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
du -sah /
```

It means:
"**S**ummarize **A**ll the files and folders, and please display it in a **H**uman readable output"

Regardless, you might prefer using the 'df' command. It is faster, and lists the output by devices, which is probably the more relevant information:

```
df -h
```

Answer (score 1):

`du -a /` will list all the files in all the directories you have *read* and *search* access to (provided you have also read access to their parent directories). It needs search permissions because it needs to be able to report the <kbd>d</kbd>isc <kbd>u</kbd>sage of those files as opposed to just listing them.

With a few `du` implementations like GNU `du`, it lists *files* indeed as opposed to *directory entries* in that if a file has several hard links (several directory entries pointing to it), only one of them will be listed so that the *file* is not listed several times.

To list all directory entries but `.` and `..`, you can use:

```
find /
```

That will also list entries in directories you have *read* and not *search* access to.

For all directory entries including `.` and `..`:

```
ls -Ra /
```

(same note about directory access).

If the intent is to compare with the number of files given by `df -i`, that's the `du -a` approach you'll want to use, but then you'd want to add the `-x` flag to limit to one file system. Also note that beside the directory access issues, it will miss files that are still open by some process but have been deleted, files that are masked by another file system, and also note that several file systems like ext4 have special reserved *files* (inodes) that are not linked to any directory, so even in the best of cases you'll find a discrepancy between the number given by `df -i /` and the one given by `du -ax /// | grep -c ///`.

See also GNU `du`'s:

```
du -sx --inodes /
```

to get that count.

Answer (score 1):

To list out all the files and directories then you do have plenty options

```
SHW@SHW:/tmp # time du . > /dev/null 

real    0m0.046s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

SHW@SHW:/tmp # time find . > /dev/null 

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

SHW@SHW:/tmp # time ls -aR > /dev/null 

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.000s

SHW@SHW:/tmp # time tree -a > /dev/null 

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

SHW@SHW:/tmp # du -sch .
4.1M    .
4.1M    total
```

Read the man pages of each command for further information

At least for above example, `tree -a` seems to be fast. 
`/tmp` directory contains the 4.1M data with 8 files and 21 directories.